# Printing the value of argMax index?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I would like to print the actual value of the argMax index (the highest probability) in this scenario:

```
const result = await model.predict(t4d); 
result.print(); // puts out: Tensor [[0.9899636, 0.0100364],]
result.as1D().argMax().print(); // prints either 0 or 1
```

Besides the index, I would want to print the actual value 0,XXXX behind argMax(). Any advice for this?

Test that doesn't work:

```
const confidence = result.dataSync<'float32'()>;
console.log(confidence);
```

Sorry if this is a question that has been answered any times, I have spent a few hours searching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the argMax index can be retrieved after getting the data of the tensors

```
const result = await model.predict(t4d);
const index = await result.as1D().argMax().data()[0]
const predict = await result.data()

// get the value
const value = result[index]
```

The other possibility would be to use topk

```
const topk = result.as1D().topk()
// get the highest value
value = topk.value() // the value here is a tensor
```

Comment: Great, this was the trick! I needed to make two small adjustments to get mine working though: `const index = result.as1D().argMax().dataSync()[0]; const predict = await result.data(); const value = predict[index];` Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The comment by vjuss returned the correct output, I do not have 50 reputation points to confirm/upvote their comment.

> const index = await result.as1D().argMax().data()[0];

returned undefined (incorrect), but

> const index = result.as1D().argMax().dataSync()[0];

returned a scalar value (correct).

Similarly,

> const predict = await result.data(); const maxprob = predict[index];

returned a float probability value (correct).

I also found that topk gave the correct result in a tensor using a slightly different function call:

const predict = await result.data();
const {maxprob, index} = tf.topk(predict);